# How to calculate orbit params for transfer before docking?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, space

I have two spacecrafts on two equatorial circular orbits with different phase angles (it could be random, I need a universal solution). Also, I know Kepler's params of both orbits. I want to move one spacecraft to another to make docking. So, this spacecraft should arrive to second's orbit at the same time when second spacecraft will be located near arrival point (for i.e. no close than 5m and no far than 10m)

So, how to find the Kepler's params of that third transfer orbit to make this transfer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, this is a somewhat transcendental calculation, which I do not think has an explicit solution, so some application of either Taylor series expansions or numeric calculations need to be employed. And still, it looks like there might not be a unique solution but the solution would depend on how much energy you would use for transfer.

There is, it seems to me, a simpler, more explicit solution. Given the initial angle between the position vectors of the two spacecrafts at the initial time $t_0$, you can calculate how long $\Delta t_1$ to wait for the two spacecrafts to reach a special convenient relative angle between their position vectors at time $t_0 + \Delta t_1$ and then to execute a Hohmann transfer orbit whose time of transfer $\Delta t_2$ allows the spacecraft 1 to leave orbit 1 and arrive at orbit 2 exactly at the time $t_0 + \Delta t_1 + \Delta t_2$ when spacecraft 2 is at this point. For the 5 meters offset arrival, you can simply rotate the initial position vector of spacecraft 2 very little, so that it is 5 meters behind the actual position.

Assume that in a two dimensional plane, a circle and an ellipse are tangent to each other and at the same time the center of the circle is a focus of the ellipse. Then, the vector from the center to the point of tangency of the circle and the ellipse is a radius-vector of the circle. Therefore, the tangent line to the circle at that point should be perpendicular to the radius-vector. But the tangent line is also tangent to the ellipse. Moreover, the radius-vector above connects the focus of the ellipse to the point of tangency and the tangent line is perpendicular to it. This is only possible at the two extreme points of the ellipse. Hence, the two concentric circular orbits can be tangent to the transfer orbit, which has as a focus the common center of the circles, exactly when the inner circular orbit is tangent to the periapsis of the elliptical orbit and the outer circular orbit is tangent to the apoapsis.

You know the radius $a_2$ of spacecraft 2's circular orbit and the radius $a_1$ of spacecraft 1's circular orbit. Let's assume $a_2 > a_1$. Then,

$$a = \frac{a_1 + a_2}{2}$$

$$e = \frac{a - a_1}{a} = \frac{2 \Big(\frac{a_1 + a_2}{2} - a_1\Big)}{a_1 + a_2} = \frac{a_2 - a_1}{a_2 + a_1}$$

The polar equation of the ellipse is then (in perifocal polar coordinates)

$$r \, =\, \frac{a(1-e^2)}{1 + e\cos(\nu)}$$

and the equation of motion along the ellipse, in terms of the true anomaly $\nu$ in case you need it, is

$$\frac{d\nu}{dt} \, =\, \frac{GM_{\text{Earth}}}{\Big(\sqrt{a \, (1-e^2)}\Big)^3} \, \Big(1 + e \cos(\nu)\Big)^2$$

To go from orbit 1 to orbit 2 along the elliptical orbit described above takes half the ellipse, so it takes half an orbital period to do that. Let's calculate this half-period $\Delta t_2$. The mean motion of the transfer orbit is $$n = \sqrt{\frac{GM_{\text{Earth}}}{a^3}}$$
and the time $\Delta t_2$ to go from periapsis to apoapsis is $$\pi = n \,\Delta t_2$$ so $$\Delta t_2 = \pi \sqrt{\frac{a^3}{GM_{\text{Earth}}}}$$

Observe that the mean motion of spacecraft 2 is $$n_2 = \sqrt{\frac{GM_{\text{Earth}}}{a_2^3}}$$

To determine the convenient initial angle $\theta_1$ that the radius vectors of spacecraft 1 and 2 should form in order for the time of arrival at spacecraft 2's orbit to be exactly the time when spacecraft 2 is there, should satisfy the equation

$$\pi = \theta_1 +  n_2\,\Delta t_2$$

i.e.

$$\theta_1 = \pi - n_2 \, \Delta t_2$$

which becomes

$$\theta_1 = \pi - \pi \, \sqrt{\frac{GM_{\text{Earth}}}{a_2^3}} \, \sqrt{\frac{a^3}{GM_{\text{Earth}}}} = \pi \left( 1 -  \sqrt{\Big(\frac{a_1 + a_2}{2\,a_2}\Big)^3\,} \,\right)$$

So we want the position vectors of the two spacecraft to form angle $\theta_1$ at time $t_0 + \Delta t_1$ in order to initiate a successful transfer orbit. However, at time $t_0$ of transfer consideration, the angle between the two position vectors is $\theta_0$, so we wait $\Delta t_1$ time until the position vectors form the desired angle $\theta_1$. Now, the goal is to calculate how much time $\Delta t_1$ we need to wait. Since the orbits 1 and 2 are circular, the true anomalies of the two spacecrafts change with time as follows:
$$\nu_1 = \nu_1(0) + n_1 \, (t - t_0)$$
$$\nu_2 = \nu_1(0) + \theta_0 + n_2 \, (t-t_0)$$
where the mean motions of the two spacecrafts are
$$n_1 = \sqrt{\frac{GM_{\text{Earth}}}{a_1^3}} \,\,\,\,\, \text{ and } \,\,\,\,\, n_2 = \sqrt{\frac{GM_{\text{Earth}}}{a_2^3}}$$
and $\nu_1(0)$ is the true anomaly of the spacecraft 1 at the initial time moment $t_0$. Observe that since $a_2 > a_1$, we have that $n_2 < n_1$. Hence $\Delta t_1$ satisfies the equation
$$\theta_1 =  2\pi k + \nu_2 - \nu_1 = 2\pi k + \nu_1(0) + \theta_0 + n_2 \, \Delta t_1 - \nu_1(0) - n_1 \, \Delta t_1 =  \theta_0  + (n_2 - n_1) \Delta t_1 = \theta_0 - (n_1 - n_2) \Delta t_1$$ for some appropriate integer $k$.
Hence
$$\Delta t_1 = \frac{2\pi k + \theta_0 - \theta_1}{n_1 - n_2}$$ where $k$ is chosen so that if $\theta_0 \geq \theta_1$ then $k=0$ but if $\theta_0 < \theta_1$ then $k = 1$. In the case $a_2 < a_1$ you switch $n_1$ and $n_2$ and argue the same way.

So, to summarize,

**Step 1.** You calculate:

The semi-major axis of the transfer orbit:
$$a = \frac{a_1 + a_2}{2}$$

The eccentricity of the transfer orbit:
$$e = \frac{a_2 - a_1}{a_2 + a_1}$$

The desired angle between the position vectors of the two spacecrafts at initiation of transfer orbit.

$$\theta_1 =  \pi \left( 1 -  \sqrt{\Big(\frac{a_1 + a_2}{2\,a_2}\Big)^3\,} \,\right)$$

**Step 2.** The waiting time $\Delta_1$ for the angle $\theta$ between the position vectors of the two spacecrafts to go from the current angle $\theta_0$ to the desired angle $\theta_1$ from step 1:
First, calculate:
$$n_1 = \sqrt{\frac{GM_{\text{Earth}}}{a_1^3}} \,\,\,\,\, \text{ and } \,\,\,\,\, n_2 = \sqrt{\frac{GM_{\text{Earth}}}{a_2^3}}$$
If $a_2 > a_1$ and $\theta_0 > \theta_1$ then
$$\Delta t_1 = \frac{\theta_0 - \theta_1}{n_1 - n_2}$$
If $a_2 > a_1$ and $\theta_0 < \theta_1$ then
$$\Delta t_1 = \frac{2\pi + \theta_0 - \theta_1}{n_1 - n_2}$$

**Step 3.** The argument of periapsis of the transfer orbit is then
$$\omega = \nu_1(0) + n_1 \, \Delta t_1$$

Thus, this transfer orbit is divided into two pieces: traveling along the initial circular orbit for time $\Delta t_1$ and then initiating and travelling along one half of an elliptical orbit with planar Kepler parameters $a, \, e, \, \omega$ for time $\Delta t_2 = \pi \sqrt{\frac{a^3}{GM_{\text{Earth}}}}$. And it looks like this is the transfer orbit with least energy expenditure.

Comment: Will it work with non-inclined and circular orbits?

Comment: Is it possible to catch spacecraft that are moving on hyperbolic trajectory?

Comment: @Robotex What I wrote works exactly for circular non-inclined orbits. Not for general orbits. That's what you asked about in your original post. For a hyperbolic trajectory, you should ask a separate question with all the details of what is given and what is sought.

Comment: "What I wrote works exactly for circular non-inclined orbits" -- what will differ in case of general orbit?

Comment: Which orbit is general? Two spacecrafts orbiting the Earth along elliptical orbits? The calculations and the constructions are more complicated and non-explicit.

Comment: Ok, I understood. Thank you